# How to serialize 3rd party class?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service that is using a 3rd party library.  The library is not serializable.

I have a custom type that is serializable and also includes a class from the 3rd party library as a property.  It looks like:

```
MyClass.ThirdPartyClass
```

The problem is when I send MyClass out of the service, ThirdPartyClass looses the values I had assigned it while in the service.  Since I don't have the source for ThirdPartyClass, I can mark it as serializable.

Is there some way to mark ThirdPartyClass as serializable or some other way to have it retain values?

Comment: You should be able to use a combination of Reflection and XmlTextWriter to enumerate over the public properties and write out to XML. I'll try to put together a sample app later tonight

Comment: Hmm, good idea.  Maybe there is something out there that does this already?  Not sure what you would search under though.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+Serialize+a+third+party+type&oq=C%23+Serialize+a+third+party+type&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.7954j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Please tell me you're not trying to serialize the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that I have handled issues like this in the past is to create a "shadow" class that you control that is serializable and contains the portions of that class that you want to exposes.

You would then have two properties in your class, one strictly for serialization and one for internal use.

For example, assuming the third-party class looks like this:

```
public class ThirdPartyClass
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

You could create a serializable version like this (assuming you are using DataContracts):

```
[DataContract()]
public class ThirdPartyClassSerializable
{
    private ThirdPartyClass m_TPC = new ThirdPartyClass();

    public ThirdPartyClassSerializable();
    public ThirdPartyClassSerializable(ThirdPartyClass oTPC)
    {
        m_TPC = oTPC;
    }

    public ThirdPartyClass GetThirdPartyClass()
    {
        return m_TPC;
    }

    [DataMember()]
    public int Property1
    {
        get
        {
            return m_TPC.Property1;
        }
        set
        {
            m_TPC.Property1 = value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember()]
    public string Property2
    {
        get
        {
            return m_TPC.Property2;
        }
        set
        {
            m_TPC.Property2 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then your root serializable class would look like:

```
[DataContract()]
public class MyClass
{
    private ThirdPartyClass m_ThirdPartyClass;

    public ThirdPartyClass ThirdPartyClass
    {
        get
        {
            return m_ThirdPartyClass;
        }
        set
        {
            m_ThirdPartyClass = value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember()]
    public ThirdPartyClassSerializable ThirdPartyClassSerialized
    {
        get
        {
            return new ThirdPartyClassSerializable(this.ThirdPartyClassNonSerialized);
        }
        set
        {
            this.ThirdPartyClass = value.GetThirdPartyClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Using this approach, the data is serialized to external callers as expected and the original class is always available to internal callers.

A secondary advantage to this is that you can expose as much or as little of the third party class as you want or need.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest to create a data transfer object that contains the data that you want to provide through your service. Instead of making the ThirdPartyClass part of MyClass, use the new DTO and map the data of the ThirdPartyClass to the DTO before returning it from the Service. Maybe a Framework like AutoMapper can support you in this task. 
Though this means some extra effort, it also creates a layer of abstraction between the clients of your service and the 3rd party library. This enabbles you to change to another library later on without having to change the interface of your service.